# upgrade a module using windows powershell with odoo 14

Tags: python, powershell, odoo, windows-server-2008, odoo-14

Want to upgrade a custom module using windows powershell having odoo 14..
I have tried following code.but it shows FILEEXIST Error

```
PS D:\odoo\server> D:\odoo\python\python.exe .\odoo-bin -c .\odoo.conf -d TEST  -u custom_module
```

I got following error

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\SERVER\\AppData\\Local\\OpenERP S.A\\Odoo\\filestore\\TEST\\fb'
```

How to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

This looks rather straightforward to me.

```
C:\\Users\\SERVER\\AppData\\Local\\OpenERP S.A\\Odoo\\filestore\\TEST\\fb
```

It's saying this file already exists. Try deleting it prior to running the command.